# Is it okay to ask user-interface related questions on StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions, site-recommendation

I know there's a separate StackExchange site for user experience, but I was wondering if questions related to user interface (not necessarily code, although code might be mentioned) are appropriate to ask on StackOverflow. Specifically, is it okay to ask more "opinion-based" questions about what the user interface should be for a specific web-app I am designing?

**Example:**

So I'm currently designing a web app that involves the user interacting with input boxes, etc. I don't want the user to lose their data if they, for example, close the page by accident, but I also don't want them to be annoyed by popup boxes asking them if they are sure they want to leave the page. I'm considering making it so that the popups only occur when the user closes the tab after interacting with something on the page, similar to what Gmail does, but this would involve a lot of changes to my code and I'm wondering if anyone else has any otther lightweight, more elegant suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: [UX.SE] would probably be better than Stack Overflow, but it's a bit hard to tell without knowing what kind of UI questions you want to ask. Do you have an example?

Comment: Updated my question with my specific question in mind.

Comment: Yes, UX is much more appropriate than SO.

Comment: Store the data in local storage, similar to how stackoverflow stores unfinished posts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think if your question seeks **opinion** about whether some UI experience solution is better, easier to use, etc., such a question doesn't really belong to SO and it's very likely that it will be closed as primarily opinion based. User Experience site is better for this kind of questions.

On the other hand, a question asking for **technical aspects** of a similar problem is ok on SO. It might be a technical problem you're facing, performance problems, layout design issues (programing design), etc.

Your example question is of the first category, in my opinion. It would be better to ask it on User Experience site.